# Looking for approach to post long text to slack through python script

Tags: python-3.x, curl, slack, slack-api

I had written a code in python to fetch the huge set (80 lines) of data from DB, now I would like to post that data in slack through webhook. I tried posting the data directly,but its not working for me, so I decided to save the data in txt/.png file and post it in slack

I tried below code in python after saving my data in report.txt file, but its not helping me

```
headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
}

data = open('\\results\report.txt')

response = requests.post('https://jjjjjjj.slack.com/services/mywebhook', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Please share me the Curl command which will fit in python script to post the attachment in slack or please suggest me any better approach to post more than 50 lines for data to slack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to upload long text as text file. That way Slack will automatically format it with a preview and users can click on it to see the whole content.

To upload a file you need to use [`files_upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) API method. With it you can also include an initial message with your upload.

Here is an example using the standard Slack library. Here I am reading the data from a file, but you would of course use your data instead:

```
import slack
import os

# init slack client with access token
slack_token = os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN']
client = slack.WebClient(token=slack_token)

# fetch demo text from file
with open('long.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()

# upload data as file
response = client.files_upload(    
    content=text,
    channels='general',
    filename='long.txt',
    title='Very long text',
    initial_comment='Here is the very long text as requested:'
)
assert response['ok']
```

The trick is to use `content` not `file` to pass the data. If you use `file` the API will try to load a file from your filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for reply. While I am using the above code, its displaying the error message as line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None.

Comment: if I am using the SLACK_Token surrounded with round brackets E.g slack_token = os.environ('SLACK_TOKEN') , its displaying the error message as TypeError: '_Environ' object is not callable

Comment: My example code is using the convention to put your slack token into an environment variable. That is much more secure than putting it into your code. For this to work you have of course to also set the environment variable SLACK_TOKEN accordingly.

Comment: so the code is correct (and don't use round bracket), but you need to define the environment variable or you get a key error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Erik. I achieved this through another method. Below code may be helpful to others headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxx-XXXXX-XXXXX',  #Bot Token
}

files = {
    'file': ('LocationOfthefile\report.txt', open('LocationOfthefile\report.txt', 'rb')),
    'initial_comment': (None, 'Some Text For Header'),
    'channels': (None, 'Channel_Names'),
}

response = requests.post('https://slack.com/api/files.upload', headers=headers, files=files)

Comment: Cool. It's a similar approach, but you are doing direct API calls with the requests library instead of using the slack library. I think using the slack library is the better approach, because you need to write less code. But your approach works too of course. How about you put your solution into a new answer?

Comment: Okay Sure, I will put it in new answer

Answer (score 1):

The below code works fine for me..... :)

```
headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxx-XXXXX-XXXXX', #Bot Token } 

files = { 
   'file': ('LocationOfthefile\report.txt', open('LocationOfthefile\report.txt', 'rb')), 
   'initial_comment': (None, 'Some Text For Header'), 
   'channels': (None, 'Channel_Names'),
 } 

response = requests.post('slack.com/api/files.upload', headers=headers, files=files)
```